# Upload File and Data with Ajax PHP formData submit XHR

Tags: php, ajax, serialization, file-upload

hello friend i am trying to upload data and files at some time via ajax with this form:

```
<form id="formarea" class="form-horizontal" name="desk">
<input type="text" class="form-control " name="i_txt_2">
<input type="number" class="form-control " name="i_txt_3" required>
<input type="file" name='i_files_1'>
<input type="file" name='i_files_2'>
<input type="file" name='i_files_3'>
</form>
```

Ajax:

```
$('[id^="save"]').on("click", function (event, xhr, settings) {
        var id = event.target.id;
        var name = $("#formarea").attr("name");
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",url:"index.php",data:$("#formarea").serialize()+ '&idprocess=' + id + '&idform=' + name,
                error: function(xhr,status,error){console.log(error)},
                success:    function(response) {
                    $("#areasmg").html(response);
                    $("#MsgArea").removeClass("").addClass("alert alert-warning alert-dismissable");
                    $("#MsgArea").show();
                }
            });
    });
```

**issues:** 
on request i am not received in server side php serialized of Input File: **i_files_1**
how can i concatenate the dile to data sent:

```
data:$("#formarea").serialize()+ '&idprocess=' + id + '&idform=' + name + '&Files' + files[]Serialized ,
```

**UPDATE** Problem Solved:

```
//If you have button to submit Form
$('[id^="BTN-"]').on("click", function (event, xhr, settings) {
    var id = event.target.id; //get id buton to filter if you like get control over the button clicked
    var req = 0;
    $('#formarea *').filter(':input').each(function(){ //filter all requiered input field
        if($(this).val() === "" && $(this).attr('required')){req ++;}
    });
    if(req == 0){
        var name = $("#formarea").attr("name"); //get name of form if you like get control over the form submited
        //window.WindowsWait();
        var input1 = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "idprocess").val(id); //Adding field for more controls if you neet handle from PHP
        var input2 = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "idform").val(name); //Adding field for more controls if you neet handle from PHP
        $('#formarea').append($(input1)); //inserting on Html
        $('#formarea').append($(input2)); //inserting on Html
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent default submit
        //get form an serialize data with FormData
        var $form       = $("#formarea"), 
            formData    = new FormData(),
            params      = $form.serializeArray();               
        var inputs = $("input[type=file]");
        //Get all Input tipe Files
        $.each(inputs, function (obj, v) {
            // Prefix the name of uploaded files with "uploadedFiles-"
            // Of course, you can change it to any string
            var file = v.files[0];
            var name = $(v).attr("name");//you can work with the name
            formData.append(name, file);
        });
        // Add all params to the formData
        $.each(params, function(i, val) {
            formData.append(val.name, val.value);
        });
        //performing the submit
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            error: function(xhr,status,error){console.log(error)},
            success:    function(response) {
                alert(response);//print response server
            }
        });

    }else{
        alert("Error: You must fill all field, there " + req + " Empty Fields.");//handle Error Empty Fields
    }
});
```

Test:

**print_r($_FILES);**

Comment: $_FILES checks for file input while $_POST handles for text and other input types

Comment: I have several questions, but first of all, why `$("#formarea").serialize()+ '&idprocess=' + id + '&idform=' + name`? Make these parameters, you try to add, part of the actual form.

Comment: Also you need to use a FormData object to upload files with AJAX

Comment: hello, thanks for responding quickly, if these data are extra, I need php side, to work properly. some Switch / Case, the details is that $ ( "# formarea"). serialize () does not send me the input file or field, are an update added support for $ _FILES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** Problem Solved:

```
//If you have button to submit Form
$('[id^="BTN-"]').on("click", function (event, xhr, settings) {
    var id = event.target.id; //get id buton to filter if you like get control over the button clicked
    var req = 0;
    $('#formarea *').filter(':input').each(function(){ //filter all requiered input field
        if($(this).val() === "" && $(this).attr('required')){req ++;}
    });
    if(req == 0){
        var name = $("#formarea").attr("name"); //get name of form if you like get control over the form submited
        //window.WindowsWait();
        var input1 = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "idprocess").val(id); //Adding field for more controls if you neet handle from PHP
        var input2 = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "idform").val(name); //Adding field for more controls if you neet handle from PHP
        $('#formarea').append($(input1)); //inserting on Html
        $('#formarea').append($(input2)); //inserting on Html
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent default submit
        //get form an serialize data with FormData
        var $form       = $("#formarea"), 
            formData    = new FormData(),
            params      = $form.serializeArray();               
        var inputs = $("input[type=file]");
        //Get all Input tipe Files
        $.each(inputs, function (obj, v) {
            // Prefix the name of uploaded files with "uploadedFiles-"
            // Of course, you can change it to any string
            var file = v.files[0];
            var name = $(v).attr("name");//you can work with the name
            formData.append(name, file);
        });
        // Add all params to the formData
        $.each(params, function(i, val) {
            formData.append(val.name, val.value);
        });
        //performing the submit
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            error: function(xhr,status,error){console.log(error)},
            success:    function(response) {
                alert(response);//print response server
            }
        });

    }else{
        alert("Error: You must fill all field, there " + req + " Empty Fields.");//handle Error Empty Fields
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A little search on Google should give you a excellent tutorial by Mozilla

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Then you forgot to add to your form tag : `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to accept file uploads.

Comment: this not work becouse it is a form with other input type= text/number

Comment: You always can mix input types ! On server side you just will have to process files with $_FILES super global and other inputs with $_POST super global.

Comment: @WalterNuñez Download the complete Solution here: http://moriche.ch/walter. Too much to post here...

Comment: @Poiz Thank you for this example, it is a great help, but the problem is that the script is generic and is used in several maintenance screen, for example within the #formarea (Form) can have many input text / num / date / ETC and need dynamically capture not static. files are jpg, pdf, excel, powerpoint, and only one input but can have several input in one form

Answer (score 0):

I cannot write/post all the information here for want of space but you can go to http://moriche.ch/walter to download a fully working solution...

Without the **Header Directive** The File will still work perfectly. Here is the content of the File:

```
    <?php
        // file-processor.php
        // HEADER HAS BEEN REMOVED, YET IT WILL STILL WORK...

        // HERE YOU CAN ACCESS ALL THE FIELDS THAT ARE CONTAINED IN THE FORM.
        // EVERY ONE OF THEM: FROM NUMBER FIELD TO TEXT AREA, ETC ;-)
        $text2          = isset($_POST['text2']) ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['text2'])) : null;
        $text3          = isset($_POST['text3']) ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['text3'])) : null;
        $arrStatus      = array();
        $arrResponse    = array();

        if(isset($_FILES['i_files_1'])){
            $fileData               = $_FILES['i_files_1'];
            $arrStatus["i_files_1"] = uploadFile($fileData);
        }

        if(isset($_FILES['i_files_2'])){
            $fileData               = $_FILES['i_files_2'];
            $arrStatus["i_files_2"] = uploadFile($fileData);
        }

        if(isset($_FILES['i_files_3'])){
            $fileData               = $_FILES['i_files_3'];
            $arrStatus["i_files_3"] = uploadFile($fileData);
        }

        function uploadFile($fileData, $uploadDir = __DIR__ . "/img"){
            $flTName    = $fileData['tmp_name'];
            $flName     = $fileData['name'];
            $flType     = $fileData['type'];
            $flSize     = $fileData['size'];
            $flErr      = $fileData['error'];

            $info       = new SplFileInfo($flName);
            $ext        = $info->getExtension();

            if(!is_dir($uploadDir)){
                mkdir($uploadDir, 0777, true);
            }

            $pixDst     = $uploadDir . "/uploaded_pix_" . generateRandomString() . "." . $ext;
            return move_uploaded_file($flTName, $pixDst);
        }


        foreach($arrStatus as $fileKey=>$boolStatus){
            if($boolStatus){
                $arrResponse[$fileKey] = $fileKey . " was successfully uploaded...";
            }else{
                $arrResponse[$fileKey] = "Error: could not upload \"{$fileKey}\"";
            }
        }

        function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
            $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $randomString = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
            }
            return $randomString;
        }


        die( json_encode($arrResponse) );
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            var text2               = $("input[name=i_txt_2]");
            var text3               = $("input[name=i_txt_3]");
            var files               = $("input[type=file]");
            var theForm             = $("#formarea");
            var formAction          = theForm.attr("action");

            files.each(function(dt, dom){
                var target = $(this);
                target.change(function(evt) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    var dis     = $(this);
                    var dis_val = dis.val();

                    // HERE YOU CAN JUST ADD THE FILE TYPES YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
                    // LIKE MP3, MP4, PDF, ETC...
                    if (dis_val && /(\.)(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/.test(dis_val)) {
                        // THE RIGHT FILES WERE UPLOADED SO DO NOTHING;
                    } else {
                        alert("Only Images in with the Format: (JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP) are allowed.");
                        dis.val(null);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });


            theForm.submit(function (evt) {
                var $this = $(this);
                evt.preventDefault();

                $this.attr("action", formAction).ajaxSubmit({
                    dataType:       "HTML",
                    success:        confirmFileUpload,
                    cache:          false
                });
            });

            function confirmFileUpload(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log("File was uploaded and the World is fine again...");
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you for this example, it is a great help, but the problem is that the script is generic and is used in several maintenance screen, for example within the #formarea (Form) can have many input text / num / date / ETC and need dynamically capture not static. files are jpg, pdf, excel, powerpoint, and only one input but can have several input in one form

Comment: @WalterNuñez  Sure... but all of those input Fields are Posted too... Even if you have 100 Input fields, they are all posted and you can access them just like you would access any posted data in php. Inside of the PHP File; simply do $_POST['field_name'] and you have the value... you may try it, if you will... ;-)

Comment: ok ok... you can help me to avoid header('Content-type: application/json'); from client side and server side becouse i have many response without JSON Encoding and need preserve this compatibilty.

Comment: @WalterNuñez Inside the PHP File **file-processor.php** ***delete the  header('Content-type: application/json')*** and the Program will still work perfectly. And there would be no conflict with any Library whatsoever... I will Post the Content of the **file-processor.php* here, now...

Comment: and the data type in JS?  dataType: "json", i go to try delete dataType Line.

Comment: @WalterNuñez    You can as well change the DATA-TYPE in the JS File to plain HTML like so: **dataType: "HTML",** and inside the PHP File, you can just respond with an Empty string like so: **die("");** instead of ***die( json_encode(...) );***...

Comment: @WalterNuñez   I updated the Post... The Javascript is now modified to only receive plain Text/HTML....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112091/discussion-between-walter-nunez-and-poiz).